# Dependency injection and Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

At the end of the example we have a line and I quote

> The example above shows the basic concept of dependency injection, the
>   `MessagePrinter` is decoupled from the `MessageService` implementation,
>   with Spring Framework wiring everything together.

The article makes an inference at the end
`MessagePrinter` is decoupled from the `MessageService`.

I do not understand how come by using some annotations the MessagePrinter has
been decoupled from the MessageService.
Anybody please care to explain?

Comment: It's not decoupled from `MessageService`, but from the **implementation** of `MessageService`. In other words, `MessagePrinter` doesn't know which implementation of `MessageService` is plugged in. And that's good, because that means it can be used with any implementation of `MessageService`.

Comment: Hi Jesper can you elaborate a bit more please

Comment: What more do you want to know? The point is that `MessagePrinter` doesn't (need to) know what implementation of the interface `MessageService` is being used. See: [Loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) for more information about why this is good.